# Skip Scanner - Server Multiple Operations

Tags: java

I have made a Server that allows to Server administrator add a user (in the commands line) and answer to client orders. I want to know how I can skip the Scanner if the Server administrator doesn't write anything in the commands line and continue to accept client orders.

```
  while(true){  

                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                String user = scan.nextLine();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/SecShareServer/passwords.txt"));
                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/SecShareServer/passwords.txt",true));
                String line = in.readLine();
                boolean exists = false;
                while(line!=null){
                    if(line.contains(user)){
                        line = line.replace("false", "true");
                        out.write(line);
                        System.out.println("\nUser added.");
                        exists = true;
                    }
                    line=in.readLine();
                    in.close();
                    out.close();
                }
                if(!exists)
                    System.out.println("\nUser doesn't exist.");
                Socket client = socket.accept();
                ThreadClient myThread = new ThreadClient(client);
                Thread thread = new Thread(myThread);
                thread.start();
            }   
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if any arguments were passed in the command line by using args.length, if none then you can skip scan declaration.